# jQuery UI tabs - clear cache data for particular tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, caching, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI tab with `cache:true` . After specific action by user i want the cache to be cleared.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797486/jquery-ui-tabs-clear-cached-tab/8798068) is the method by using

```
$("#tabs .ui-tabs-nav a").removeData("cache.tabs");
```

to clear cache data of all tabs.

I need to clear cache of a particular tab not all. I tried with

```
$("#tabs .ui-tabs-nav a#idOfTab").removeData("cache.tabs");
```

but it is not working. It is still removing cache data of all the tabs.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

$("#tabs .ui-tabs-nav a#idOfTab").removeData("cache.tabs");

This works for me:

$("#idOfLi a").removeData("cache.tabs");