# jQuery-ui tabs: clear cache

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to clear the cache of a loaded tab so that on the next tab click it is reloaded. The solution from [JQuery UI Tabs - Clear Cached Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797486/jquery-ui-tabs-clear-cached-tab) doesn't work for me, and I don't know what's wrong. The question/answer doesn't show the actual code used, so the setup might be slightly different to mine.

See http://jsfiddle.net/A3SHj/ for my use case.

My setup code:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    //see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-cache
    cache:true, //make click only load page once
    ajaxOptions: { cache: false }, //but don't cache the ajax request!
    active:0 //first tab is active
  });
});
```

My clear-cache function:

```
function clearTabsCache() {
  //see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797486/jquery-ui-tabs-clear-cached-tab
  $("#tabs .ui-tabs-nav a").removeData("cache.tabs");
}
```

For example using Chrome's developer tools you can observe in the Network panel that the PNG in the "Remote page" tab is only fetched once, not re-fetched after 'clear tab cache'. (The fact that the browser shows the image byte stream is not of interest here.)

The js code `$("#tabs .ui-tabs-nav a")` correctly selects the 2 tabs, and the removeData() method succeeds, but there's no change.

Comment: As a side note, I believe that the jquery-ui (tabs) widget should provide api methods for dealing with the cache.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the answer over here

[JQuery UI Tabs caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624228/jquery-ui-tabs-caching/3623807#3623807)

This will do the trick for you. You can control the caching of individual tab

In your case when using above answer just use

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
cache: true,
itemOptions: [
    { cache: true },
    { cache: false }
]
});
```